# AddRelativeForce() causes unwanted turning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've create a movement script that moves a character (ship) in a topdown view.
Gravity is disabled, but the rest of the settings i left mostly alone.

I'm applying a constant force in the forward or backward direction (local, so relative to the character NOT the world). This however causes some movement in other directions if the character is rotated for some reason.

```cs
                Debug.Log(nameof(force) + force);

                rigidBody2D.AddRelativeForce(force);
```

Lets me explain with pictures.

Starting point:
[image]

Moving forward somewhat (works okay):
[image]

Back to starting point (stopping game, starting anew)
And then i manually change the rotation to -90 in the inspector.
I then move forward somewhat.

[image]

As we can see since the rotation is -90, moving forward in relative to the character (AddRelativeForce(..)) causes it to move to the right on the screen.
The `X` position increments accordingly.

However, also the `Y` component changes, the character gets velocity in this direction, even though i apply no force in that direction - which we can see in the output.

How can I move my character with force without this issue?

Edit:

Here are the project files. Runs under the latest unity `2020.1.14f1`. The logic mentioned here is located in MoveExecuteSystem. I use a small ECS framework: https://github.com/Leopotam/ecs

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b86dfb27b4388b85ac4fef285d87b39520201124193329/00af66

Comment: Code cited in question works for me. Please include a [mre] in the question. Is the vertical movement perceivable? It is hard to tell from the image but is the vertical position/velocity something that is almost zero like -1.069158e-7?

Comment: @Ruzihm i've added the project files, runs under the latest unity `2020.1.14f1`. Unfortunately i'm lacking time at the moment or else i would've made an actual minimal reproducable sample lol. The vertical movement is indeed perceivable, the velocity goes up to 2 or something out of the top of my head.

Comment: @Ruzihm ah right, theres also `StabilizeExecuteSystem` which lowers the velocity if nu buttons are pressed, you may want to uncomment the code in the Run function so it does nothing.

Comment: @Ruzihm Posting the entire project was the only way i could think of to create a minimal reproducible sample.

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that [AddRealtiveForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html) adds the force in the local coords system. If the force vector has got always the same value, the outcome is going to be different depending on the rotational position of the entity.
To solve this, you need to apply the force such as: `Vector3 force = myShip.forward * forceValue` where force value can be an `int` or a `float`.
It can be `myShip.up` or `myShip.right` depending on what you want. My point is that with the `.forward`, `.up` or `.right` you always will apply the force according to the instant local coordinate system rotational position.

EDIT:
This question seems deeper than I thought, I made the trial in a project myself, and actually there are variations in the position when you apply force **only when the object is rotated**. Had a quick look and don't know why this is. Seem to be a precisión thinh regarding the rotations of the physics the rigidbody uses under the hood.
I tried to remove the friction which I thought might be also cause of the problem but seems not possible. +1 to this question and lookig forward to know the answer.

EDIT2:
Bounciness and friction can be set to 0 if a new physics material 2d is created, but the issue persists.
You can freeze position in determined axis as a solution, but this does not explain the position variation problem.

Comment: That's exactly what i'm doing, i want to add force relatively, however when i add force with (0, 15) (X left/right, Y fwd,bwd) and i rotate my object, it will suddenly not only move forward (relatively speaking) but also on the other axis. I.e. i apply force in one direction, and i get velocity in both x and Y

Comment: OK, I was edditing the answer because I expected so, although its not shown in the code. Try putting the scale to (1,1,1). Many times scales different from 1 produce unexpected outcomes in rotations due to the order of the transformations. I think that can be the problem.

Comment: ah, no thats what i want to do. I set the scale to 1,1,1 however that did not affect this issue :/ good to know that that causes problems though.

Comment: okay. Another thing I would try even though I am not familiar with that parameter is put the angular drag to 0 or a very high value. Trial-error ;)

Comment: haha yeah i was already onto that one. Also added a physics material and set bounciness/friction to zero - bu that all did not work.

Comment: I think then that the problem might be that your local center of mass is not (0,0). Its true that that issue should be provoking a torque also when you move along y, because the local centre of mass is displaced in both of the axis. Anyhow you can check if arranging the gameobject to have the local center of mass centered solves the issue.

Comment: Another approach to compensate the center of mass displacement is apply the force in the center of mass itself if it is desplaced, instead of in the gameObject's pivot with 
 [addForceAtPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition.html) to avoid the undesired torque

Comment: hmm.. thanks for bearing with me on this btw. I've set the pivot to 'center' on the sprite. I found no options to set the center of mass from the inspector, i've removed all colliders so the center of mass is 0,0 but i observe the same behaviour. When rotating in that case the local centre of mass stays put, but the world centre of mass changes in both directions (seems obvious because its moving in both directions). man physics is hard.

Comment: no problem, we are together on this, lol. Its normal that the world center of mas changes, its just the center of mass world coords of the ship, changing along with the ship movement.

Comment: make sure that there is not any other game objec in the ship hierarchy that might be having a rigidbody component with the gravity enabled

Comment: last shot is to move the ship with code handling the transform instead of using physics and forces. But I would not consider that option as it involves defeat

Comment: `AddRelativeForce` applies force at center of mass so the position of the center of mass should not matter unless a collision or some other component is coming into play.

Comment: @rustyBucketBay i've completely stripped the character but that did not help unfortunately. It must be someting so small or simple i'm overlooking or setup wrong. When i have more time i think i'll recreate some things.

Comment: @rustyBucketBay i've awarded the bounty  to you, since you've been most (and the most) helpful with figuring this issue out, although i don't see any real solutions in sight yet... I'm wondering if i can manually calculate the force with the rotation so that i can use `AddForce()`  instead, and see if that does not have the same issue.

Comment: I was moved more by the desire to solve the problem that by the award, however thanks a lot. I dont know If you are going to be able to manually calculate the force you are talking about, because for that we would need to know how that residual torque is produced to compensate it, which is the core of the question. If you post any outcome on your investigations in the question I will be glad to know. Regards ;)